# Add tag to selected text in textarea with description[] and description[<?php echo $i; ?>]

Tags: jquery, tags, textarea

I have the following code in a text area field:

```
NAME="description[$i]" ID="description[$i]"><?php echo $product_description[$i]; ?>
```

and I would like to add a simple `<b></b>` to the selected text in this field, without a html text editor, and with a javascript cross-browser solution.

And for this code to:

```
NAME="description[]" ID="description[]"><?php echo $description; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm understand you wrongly but you can try using [rangyinputs](https://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/):

```
$("#test").surroundSelectedText("<b>", "</b>");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BwnsS/)